# Windows 8.1 Freeze when Restarting

Tags: windows-8.1

I have HP Laptop and I use Win 8.1 Pro and I faced a problem that when I restart my PC the restart screen opens and the spinning dots stay rounding for 3 to 5 seconds then the PC freeze suddenly and I have to shutdown it by Long-press the power button.

Comment: Boot into safe mode, to accomplish this, cause windows to fail three times.  You will presented the ability to boot into safe mode after that point.

Comment: Run the memory and hard drive fitness tests from the HP bios, post back any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you've the recovery disks of Windows 8.1, Plug it in the USB port and restart your PC using the recovery media. Try using refresh options in Windows 8.1 to make your PC as refresh as new.

In case you don't have the recovery media, I'm afraid that you've to borrow installation media and perform a fresh installation of Windows 8.1.

P.S. There does't seems any hardware problems. So you shouldn't worry about replacing any hardware equipment.

Good luck though!!